# General definition of Surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, surfaces, spheres

What is a definition of a sphere that contains only topological information? And that of a torus? I can only Think of definitions like "points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that satisfies: $f(x) = 0$" but is there a more General way of defining at Least some Surfaces? Let's take $n=3$ as a reference.

Comment: If you're not talking about specific shapes (which is geometry, and not topology), then you need to specify a sphere as a compact surface of genus $0$ and a torus as a compact surface of genus $1$, etc. But generally *shapes* have more information than just their underlying topology.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you! So what would be like this definition? Can you give me some references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "surface" can be defined in subtly different ways depending on the context. Two definitions that seem useful to your purposes are:

> A **topological $2$-manifold (without boundary) in $\mathbb R^n$** is a set $M\subset \mathbb R^n$ such that, for all $p \in M$, there exists an open set $U$ such that $p\in U$ and $U\cap M$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.
>
> A **topological $2$-manifold with boundary in $\mathbb R^n$** is a set $M\subset \mathbb R^n$ such that, for all $p \in M$, there exists an open set $U$ such that $p\in U$ and $U\cap M$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ or to the half-plane $\text{H}^2=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2: y \geq 0\}$.

Sometimes these definitions can be modified and restricted $-$ for example, it's quite common to demand that both the homeomorphism and its inverse be smooth functions, in which case $M$ is called a **smooth manifold** rather than a topological manifold.

Classifying a particular surface $M$ as a sphere, torus, disc, etc. usually involves treating $M$ as a topological subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and describing some of the topological invariants of that space in the hope of classifying $M$ up to homeomorphism or up to [homotopy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence), which is a weaker condition (homeomorphic spaces are always homotopy equivalent, but not vice versa).

Some of these invariants are probably familiar from general topology $-$ e.g. a distinction is often made between compact and non-compact manifolds. Others are less likely to be familiar. The most important ones are probably the [homotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group) and [homology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)#Surfaces) groups associated with $M$, which together characterize it quite extensively. Unfortunately, the definitions are often quite complex and laboured. However, they are closely associated with simpler invariants, such as the [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics)) and the [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic). The definition of the Euler characteristic, in particular, is both relatively accessible and of considerable historical importance.

One can also talk about $M$ as a topological space on its own without having it inherit a subspace topology from $\mathbb R^n$. This takes more work, but it's possible to topologically characterize surfaces without worrying about what space they're embedded into.

There is quite a lot to say about topological classification of manifolds and entire fields of study dedicated mostly to this topic, so I'm only barely scratching the surface here (excuse the pun). But I hope it is a least a little helpful as a jumping off point.